# lsusb shows USB devices that are not connected

Tags: usb, hardware, usb-device

I have the weird issue that lsusb shows USB devices that are not connected. We have a couple of devices connected via USB. To disconnect them from the system we disable the power to the USB port with a special hub-like device.

Afterwards the devices are gone (you can see that on the device) but lsusb still shows the old entries. What does this mean? Are there dangling and invalid handles to these devices left on the system/OS?

Comment: Post the output of `lsusb` and `cat /proc/bus/usb/devices`

Answer (score 0):

Normally that shouldn't be. As SHW suggested, you should provide extra information (I cannot comment yet, so I have to write an answer).

However, don't forget that most externally alimented hubs can actually function even if not alimented. Depending on the number of USB devices and the internal of the hub, the computer might not be able to provide enough power to wake up the devices, but it can be enough to identify the devices.

If unplugging the hub remove the entries, then this is why. If not, I'll delete my answer (as this should have been a comment).